# How can I use LaCie USB Key "Private Volumes" with 10.6.8/10.7?

Tags: macos, software, usb, filesystem

Today I purchased a LaCie iamaKey v2. When I first ran the included 'La-Private' software, it urged me to install MacFUSE, so I did. After going through the steps, I tried to open my Private Volume, though it wouldn't open.. So, I formatted the drive, and then downloaded the software, and went through the steps again. Though now I get an error message...

```
/Library/Filesystems/fusefs.fs/Support/fusefs.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext)
  link error; check the system/kernal logs for errors or try kextutil(8).  
  the MacFUSE file system is not available (71)
```

**EDIT:** After some more research, I found that I had to use a specific version of MacFUSE. If you're a Mac user and have the above issue, check out the 'Important Note' [here](http://www.lacie.com/us/support/drivers/driver.htm?id=10241).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different, James! If you have found out a solution to your problem, please submit it as an answer. To do this, scroll down the page, and click on `Answer Your Question` to submit your answer.

Comment: I can't.. Due to the restriction of reputation points...

Answer (score 1):

To use La-Private OSX Lion users must download the update from [LaCie](http://www.lacie.com/us/support/drivers/driver.htm?id=10241) and also install the latest [MacFUSE](http://www.lacie.com/download/drivers/MacFUSE%20Core.dmg) package.